# What is the connection between Eulerian numbers and this identity?

Tags: probability, reference-request, eulerian-numbers

It is stated [in this pdf](http://arminstraub.com/downloads/math/euleriannumbers-presentation.pdf) that for $X_j \text{ iid},$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1],$

$$\dfrac{1}{n!} \left\langle n \atop k \right\rangle = P\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j\in[k,k+1]\right)$$

without further qualification. Despite multiple searches, I can't find a reference to the identity, or a proof anywhere. Where might I find an outline of a proof for this particular identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **Theorem** $\mathbf{2.1}$ in Kingo Kobayashi, Hajime Sato, Mamoru Hoshi, and Hiroyoshi Morita, [*Eulerian numbers revisited: Slices of hypercube*](http://ita.ucsd.edu/workshop/14/files/paper/paper_133.pdf) [PDF]; their proof is short, about a page.

Comment: great - thank you - feared the question had got lost in the pile! Took me a while to equate $F_{n,k}$ with Euler numbers, but looks good :)

Comment: @martin: You’re welcome. (I’m used to thinking of Eulerian numbers in terms of the number of ascents, so it took me a minute to realize that $k$ runs was equivalent to $n-k$ ascents and hence also to $k$ ascents. But it’s a clever argument.)

Comment: and I agree with them, that it is a fascinating equality! :)